# C# список ресурсов локализации

Tags: c#, resources, локализация

Сейчас я реализовал локализацию с помощью ресурсов (Strings*.resx), и столкнулся с двумя проблемами:

1. Выбор языка

Я хочу сделать выбора языка в приложении. Но как приложению узнать, какие языки доступны? Я, конечно, могу просто забить в список имена папок, содержащих `Имя_приложения.resources.dll`, так как они отражают 2 буквы языка локализации, по которому можно создать `CultureInfo`. Но мне кажется, есть более простой и правильный путь, о котором я не знаю.

2. User-friendly локализация

По умолчанию, моя программа имеет 2 ресурса локализации: по умолчанию (английский) и русский. Ресурсы – не самая удобная вещь для редактирования пользователем, особенно после компиляции. Мне бы хотелось создать папку Localization, в ней – .txt файлы локализации со структурой вида

```
ключ значение
ключ_2 значение 2
ключ_3 значение\n3
```

При запуске программа читает эти файлы и **создаёт из них ресурсы локализации**. Как создавать ресурс – я, вроде, нашёл – `Strings.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(new CultureInfo("xx-XX"),true,true)`. И то, я не уверен, что это сработает. А как мне с ним работать? Как помещать туда ключи и значения?

Обобщу вопросы:

Как получить список файлов-ресурсов локализации? Как добавить файл локализации програмно? Как програмно прочитать или добавить ключ или значение определённого языка (не текущего)? Если что-то из этого сделать нельзя¹, то есть ли другие методы локализации, такие же programmer-friendly как ресурсы {Сейчас я просто пишу строку на дефолтном языке, вызываю Resharper, он помещает эту строку в ресурсы (заодно подцепляя такие же строки) и открывает менеджер локализаций (таблицу), где я могу произвести локализацию этой строки для других языков.}?

¹ Но всё равно напишите, как сделать то, что можно

Comment: 1. Если вы сами добавляете поддерживаемые языки, то логично, если вы же и определите сами, какие языки показывать. То есть я тут проблемы не вижу, если честно

Comment: 2. непонятно, зачем вообще юзеру лазать в локализацию? Вот у вас будет 3 языка подерживаться, и вы будете новую фишку добавлять в программу, вы для новой фишки переводы добавите в свои ресурсы. После вы попросите всех юзеров, у которых свои переводы, добавлять новые слова туда? Это не выглядит как юзер френдли ес честно

Comment: 1. Эти языки я добавляю через ресурсы. пользователь так делать не может, поэтому остальные (пользовательские) языки подгружаются из файлов. Я не определяю заранее какой-то ограниченный список языков, он должен генерироваться автоматически

2. Да, как и везде, где есть такого типа локализация. Если не захотят – не проблема, просто новые фишки не будут локализованы, весь старый перевод работать будет без проблем

Comment: Проходили уже с тем же Total Commander эту историю. Плохая система, при ближайшем обновлении пользовательская локаль становится дырявая. Поэтому лучше делать только свои и только гарантированно полноценные локали, а для надежности при сборке вшивать их прямо в экзешник, чтобы обычный юзер не мог ничего поменять. Вообще ресурсы - штука не изменяемая в рантайме. Если вы модифицируете ресурсы, то это уже не ресурсы, а данные. Где хранить и как грузить данные - вам решать.

Comment: aepot, разве дырявая локаль хуже, чем никакая?

Comment: А кто вам мешает сделать полноценные локали на столько языков, сколько потребуется? Если хотите творчества пользователей в локалях, заведите гитхаб с локалями и путь они туда контрибутят по всем правилам опенсорца

Comment: Я так и сделал. Только вот мне кажется, что .txt файл с простой структурой будет для них удобнее, чем .resx с кучей xml мусора

Comment: Раз уж хотите текстовый формат, то можно вот это https://habr.com/ru/post/432786/ (GNU gettext), очень популярная система, мы ее в питоновских проектах используем с локализацией на 16 языков довольно крупных проектов. Есть и различные приложения для редактирования файлов локализации, да и формат настолько простой, что вы сами без труда приложение для редактирования таких файлов сможете написать. Из-за этой простоты gettext со своими .po файлами очень популярен. XML тоже используем, но без специализированного софта его весьма проблематично редактировать.

Comment: @aepot Выглядит как то, что нужно, спасибо!, опробую.

Comment: @aepot Попробовал, не получилось Вот тут создал обсуждение https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137406/ngettext-poedit-

Comment: Пока что смирился с трудностями для локализации со стороны пользователей и делаю её с помощью ресурсов. Вопрос 1 по-прежнему актуален